# A horror movie about a girl hunting people with a species coming out of her stomach?

Tags: story-identification, horror

I watched a horror movie like 15 years back if I am not wrong. It involves a girl hunting people (during intercourse I think) by a some sort of species thing (aloe vera kind) coming out of her stomach which will kill them instantly. It was really good at that time.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114508/

Comment: @Shreedhar - or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_II

Comment: @Shreedhar - or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_III which would still fit the timescale

Comment: @Valorum yes. that's the best conclusion we can come to based on the info given by the OP

Comment: coool, I think that's the one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Movie/TV series with a scene of spiky, black goo growing out of a lab container?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197931/movie-tv-series-with-a-scene-of-spiky-black-goo-growing-out-of-a-lab-container)

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above